# Auto-Completion In wxPython wxComboBox

Tags: python, combobox, autocomplete, wxpython, autosuggest

I've been trying to make a ComboBox which would suggest options as you type, much like an IDE's code suggestions/code-sense, or googles suggestions when you type in a search.

The suggestions would be the items from the ComboBox dropdown, which contained the substring typed in the text box of the ComboBox.

I've tried to make a ComboBox do it, with no luck, I've tried the masked ComboBoxes, and have even tried to subclass the ComboCrtl, but I've always run into troubles either performance wise or not being able to do what I want at all

I have around 2500 items in my list of items (suggestions), and simply clearing the ComboBox and inserting the items which match is way too slow.

How would I go about making such a ComboBox, or is there even a built-in feature i could use?

I can allow a small delay before the suggestions are shown, but the whole window hanging for a second or two is not acceptable, in my oppinion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Few years ago I made a control like this by subclassing TextCtrl. It supports HTML formating for suggestions. [Here you go.](http://bitbucket.org/raz/wxautocompletectrl)

There is also the [Combo Box that Suggests Options](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Combo%20Box%20that%20Suggests%20Options)

Comment: Thank you Tony,
This is not exactly what I needed, but it definitely pointed me in the right direction.
I still need the regular combobox features, so I might stitch your completion feature on to a combobox.

Comment: Your repo is gone, but the Combo Box with suggested options from the wiki works great still with the latest wxPython.