# auto-completion feature for wxpython widgets similar to ajax

Tags: python, wxpython

Is there any auto-completion feature in wxpython that can be used for drop-down menu, text control and similar types of widgets? I want the feature to work in similar fashion as ajax script in html. My problem is selecting from drop-down is too cumbersome when I have more than hundreds to select form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wxPython wiki has a couple recipes:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/AutoCompletion
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/TextCtrlAutoComplete

And there's a stack answer too: [Auto-Completion In wxPython wxComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051988/auto-completion-in-wxpython-wxcombobox)